# Catching “angular could not be found on the window” in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, exception, protractor

I have an angular.js app that connects to a STS for login. When i run the tests i need to login through the STS. But when i navigate away to the STS and come back randomly

> angular could not be found on the window

error occurs. 
What i want to do is to catch this error and retry login because this is not an issue with the tests i have written. But i can't find where to attach the error handler. For example for a returning promise we can attach `.catch()` to handle the error. 
So to handle this error where should i attach the `.catch()` or is there similar way of handling this.?

Comment: On which line in the code the error is thrown?

Comment: I do something similar.  I set `browser.ignoreSyncronization=true;`, login in through non-angular app, it redirects me to angular app, `browser.ignoreSyncronization=false; browser.refresh()`

Comment: Thanks @emory. You made a typo in your code though. It's browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; with a H. I copy-pasted your code and it failed at first because of that.

Comment: @alcfeoh sorry for the typo, but glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @emery, this trick worked for me:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;
```